# Multiple datagrid string filters in Clarity

Tags: datagrid, vmware-clarity

Does anyone know how to use multiple built-in string filters in the datagrid in clarity components ?
Link: https://v2.clarity.design/datagrid/built-in-filters

It seems when I have 2 string filters only one of them works

Another question is that how to make the string filter more dynamic, if I have to use the string filter in multiple datagrids I need to duplicate the filter since the whole row is passed in to the filter. In the filter I would somehow need to tell which field in the JSON object (row) to filter by

-Jani

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is working after update to 2.2.2 (https://clarity.design/news)